# How to pull values from a json object that looks like "key":[10,12,56] with Java

Tags: java, android, json

In wordpress an Api I use returns the tags' ids in an odd way, it returns in this ways:

```
"tags":[50,51,54]
```

I have never seen any Json that doesn't look like "key":"value", and I got no clue how to parse it...
I hope you can help, Thank you!

Update: 
My bad, the example I posted was not a full json, it looks like that:

```
{"categories":[2,8],"tags":[50,51,54]}
```

Comment: that's because it is not a valid JSON.Is that full JSON you get?

Comment: This is not valid JSON, but it would be if it looked like this: `{"tags":[50,51,54]}`. It is an object with a property `tags` which is an array of three numbers.

Comment: But How do I access such thing? After I create a JsonObject

Comment: you will be unable to create JSONObject from it. It will throw exception, as JsonObject can be created only from valid JSON

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Why? This is a perfectly valid object (with the braces of course).

Comment: @Henry, probably because I said nothing about braces.

Comment: The website jsoneditoronline.org does succeed to parse it... it seems as it's valid as Henry said, I just can't understand how to access it values...

Comment: Depending on the JSON library you use there might be a method `obj.getJSONArray("tags")` to access the array value.

Comment: @NegevAsaf Hi Negev, why dont you try with below approach which i have mentioned in Answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-do-i-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: I know how to Parse a Json... this is an irregular json, at least for me

Comment: this is 100% regular JSON. If it looks irregular to you, then `I know how to Parse a Json` is wrong

Comment: But how can you access the values of a json that doesn't look like "key":"valuse"? Thanks!

Comment: `[50,51,54]` is a value of type `JsonArray`

Comment: Why don't you tell us which JSON library you are using? We could give a more useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [] indicate that the tags are stored as an array.  You can use [`JSONObject.getJSONArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html#getJsonArray-java.lang.String-) to access the array as a JSONArray object, then use `.getInt()` to retrieve the values.  For example:

```
    String jsonString = "{\"categories\":[2,8],\"tags\":[50,51,54]}";
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONArray tagsArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("tags");
    // Transfer JSONArray to an int[] array.
    int tags[] = new int[tagsArray.length()];
    for (int i=0; i<tagsArray.length(); i++) {
        tags[i] = tagsArray.getInt(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class for this json string and parse the json with just one line of code as shown in main method.

```
public class Example {

    private List<Integer> categories = null;
    private List<Integer> tags = null;

    public List<Integer> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(List<Integer> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    public List<Integer> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(List<Integer> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "{\"categories\":[2,8],\"tags\":[50,51,54]}";
        Example example = new Gson().fromJson(str, Example.class);
        System.out.println(example.getCategories());
        System.out.println(example.getTags());
    }
}
```

You need to have gson library for this and have this import,

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
```

Hope this works for you.